# Can a java .classpath refer to a .jar file within the eclipse plugin folder independant of install location?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have an Eclipse plugin which stores its class library at `\plugins\edu.wpi.first.javadev.sunspotfrcsdk_1.0.6.5\sunspotfrcsdk\lib\WPILibJ\classes.jar` within the Eclipse install directory. At present, the `.classpath` uses an absolute path, so breaks when the project is run on another computer.

How can I make the `.classpath` refer to a .jar file using a path relative to the eclipse install directory?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins should generally be referenced in eclipse .classpath as Libraries not Jars.

if you look at the .classpath file you'll see this distinction:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="webdriver-tests"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib-new/test/hamcrest-all.jar"/>
```

The kind src is a source folder the kind con is a Library, and kind lib is regular jar.

You'll notice the kind="con" points to a static container for the library and is not dependent on a path.  Plugins should provide this container and you can add them to your build path through project context menu

> Build Path->Configure Build Path...->Add Library

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

**Note that all developers will need the plugin installed for this to work.**

Comment: My plugin does not provide a container. Should I add a user library?

Comment: Instead, it just injects its library into the classpath of **every goddam project** whenever it updates...

Comment: @Eric what's the plugin exactly?

Comment: Its a poorly written plugin for a robotics competition (FRC) that adds a build option for sending the code to the controller, and a perspective no sane person would ever use. I don't particularly want to write the plugin from scratch, but I would quite like it to "just work".

Comment: Hmm it may be that the plugin is poorly written, looks like there is a netbeans plugin.  Maybe time to experiment with netbeans? :) A misbehaving plugin is not easy to work around.

Comment: So there's no way for me to relatively-link to those class libraries?

Comment: @eric can you provide the update site for the plugin? Maybe there's something we can figure out.

Comment: [Sure](http://first.wpi.edu/FRC/java/eclipse/update/stable/). Thanks for the advice so far!